# Angular: How do I Rxjs filter by property through an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, rxjs, rxjs5

What is the correct way to apply an RXJS v5.5 filter to an array of objects?

I am getting back a json array that looks like this:

```
[
    0: {CompanyName: "Facebook Inc-A", Symbol: "FB", is_etf: false},
    1: {CompanyName: "Flagstar Bancp", Symbol: "FBC", is_etf: false},
    2: {CompanyName: "UBS AG FI Enhanced Large Cap Growth ETN", etf_data: {…}, Symbol: "FBGX", is_etf: true},
    3: {CompanyName: "Fortune Brd H&S", Symbol: "FBHS", is_etf: false},
    4: {CompanyName: "Fortress Biotec", Symbol: "FBIO", is_etf: false},
    5: {CompanyName: "First Bus Finl", Symbol: "FBIZ", is_etf: false},
...]
```

I need to keep values with `is_etf === false`

I currently have:

...

```
.switchMap(val => this.symbolSearchService.symbolLookup(val))
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      .filter((value) => {
        console.log(value)
        return true
      })
      .subscribe(val => {
        console.log('val', val)
        this.searchResults = val;
      });
```

symbolLookup returns the array referenced above. inside the filter I've tried:

`value => !value.is_etf`

`value => return value.is_etf === false`

`value => value['is_etf'] === false`

but none of these work, as the is_etf property is on each object, not on the value response. Before RXJS I would've just done a for loop and then just go with `value[i]['is_etf']` etc but no luck here. All the reading materials I've encountered are doing simple filters like value => value > 2 ... any advice?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` operator in RxJS does not behave like the `Array.filter` function used for filtering out items from a list.

What you are actually getting from `this.symbolSearchService.symbolLookup(val)` seems to be an array, so the type of the emmission in `filter` will also be an array. So, what you might be looking for is a `map` operator that forwards the filtered list, like that:

```
.switchMap(val => this.symbolSearchService.symbolLookup(val))
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      .map((values) => {
        return values.filter(v => !v.is_etf);
      })
      .subscribe(val => {
        console.log('val', val)
        this.searchResults = val;
      });
```

Comment: Will look into map, thanks @ggradnig. Oh yes this worked!! Thanks again!

Comment: this looks like a typing problem.. you need to declare an interface for the data type you are receiving and returing it  at this.symbolSearchService.symbolLookup(val)